# prove if $m\leq f(x)\leq M$ for all $x\in[a,b]$ then $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=(b-a)\mu$ for $m\leq\mu\leq M$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

i need help with this exercise
prove if $m\leq f(x)\leq M$ for all $x\in[a,b]$ then $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=(b-a)\mu$ for $m\leq\mu\leq M$

I try this:

Well, which $f$ is integrable in $[a,b]$ and $m\leq f(x)\leq M$ then $m(b-a)\leq\int_{a}^{b}f\leq M(b-a)$, i know this: $m(b-a)\leq sup\left\{ L(F,P)\right\} \leq\int_{a}^{b}f\leq inf\left\{ U(f,P)\right\} \leq M(b-a)$ if i prove $sup\left\{ L(f,P)\right\} =\mu(b-a)$ the exercise is solve. Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $\mu=\frac{\int_a^b f}{b-a}$. Then divide $m(b-a)\leq\int_{a}^{b}f\leq M(b-a)$ by $b-a$ to get your result.

Comment: EXCELLENT MAN, THIS PROOF IS VERY VERY CLEAR.

Answer (score 1):

You do have $m(b-a)\le \int_a^bf(x)~dx\le M(b-a)$. Consider the function $g(x)=(b-a)x$ on the interval, $[m,M]$. Apply the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: but that requires continuity...

Comment: @Momo $g(x)$ is continuous, and it's quite trivial to prove.

Comment: you are right. I was writing the same thing but for some reason it seemed to me that he is asking the intermediate value theorem for integrals.